# Better programming in a Haskell Tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I have this situation:

```
data BT1 a = Nd a (BT1 a) (BT1 a) | Lf deriving (Show, Eq)
data trG = trG { title :: String, authors :: [String], price :: Double }
                 deriving (Show, Eq, Ord) 

g1 = trG "Alsace" ["JP Robin"] 45
g2 = trG "Picardie" ["Auguste Renoir"] 40
g3 = trG "Gironde" ["Alain Schwartz"] 35
g4 = trG "France" ["Jean Dalverny"] 42
g5 = trG "GB" ["Vidal Cameron"] 50
g6 = trG "Germany" ["Auguste Renoir"] 48
g7 = trG "USA" ["John Kennedy"] 60
```

g1..g7 are in a BT1 tree (not assumed to be binary)

```
gtNam = Nd g4
         (Nd g6
          (Nd g5 Lf Lf)
          (Nd g1 Lf Lf) )
         (Nd g2
          (Nd g3 Lf Lf)
          (Nd g7 Lf Lf) )
```

a function trying to find a book of a given author in the tree gtNam
(giveAuthor and giveTitle are two small functions, they give Author and Title of a book)

```
treeFindAuthorBook :: String -> BT1 trG -> [[Char]]
treeFindAuthorBook _ Lf = [""]
treeFindAuthorBook str (Nd v l r) = do
  let m = find (==str) (giveAuthor v)
  if m == Nothing
    then do
      k <- treeFindAuthorBook str l
      if  k == ""
        then treeFindAuthorBook str r
        else 
         [k]
    else
      return (giveTitle v)
```

1) I would like to write it in a more Haskell-like way

2) How can I do to accumulate in a list all of the books possibly written by a given author?

Comment: You know you can't have data types and constructors start with a lower case letter?  `data trG = trG ...` won't compile.

Comment: @ bheklilr : Mistake when I copied that with a few modifications from  my .hs file :-)

Comment: I find these abbreviations very hard to read. What's wrong with writing `Leaf` and `Node` instead of `Lf` and `Nd`? The longer version is easier to read not only for us, but also for your future self. Am I the only one who has no clue what `TrG` stands for?

Comment: Sorry for that! I modified my .hs file to abbreviate and stay as short as possible :-( TrG stands for TravelGuide...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write the treeFindAuthorBook in a more functional way like this assuming you are using GHC:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

data BT1 a = Nd a (BT1 a) (BT1 a) | Lf deriving (Show, Eq)
data TrG = TrG { trgTitle :: String, trgAuthors :: [String], trgPrice :: Double }
                 deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)


treeFindAuthorBook :: String -> BT1 TrG -> [String]
treeFindAuthorBook _ Lf = []
treeFindAuthorBook author (Nd TrG {..} left right)
  | author `elem` trgAuthors = trgTitle : rest
  | otherwise = rest
  where
    rest = treeFindAuthorBook author left ++ treeFindAuthorBook author right
```

The 'RecordWildcars' directive at the beginning enables the ghc-specific syntactic extension, where we can use the field names of the TrG "directly". See also [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html).

EDIT: Note that I've renamed the record fields by prepending the 'trg-' prefix, which is more or less a convention to avoid name collisions...

If you want to return a list of books instead of the titles then it is easy to adapt the solution above:

```
treeFindAuthorBook :: String -> BT1 TrG -> [TrG]
treeFindAuthorBook _ Lf = []
treeFindAuthorBook author (Nd book@TrG {..} left right)
  | author `elem` trgAuthors = book : rest
  | otherwise = rest
  where
    rest = treeFindAuthorBook author left ++ treeFindAuthorBook author right
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution which don't import too much modules still unknown from an almost beginner in Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

Some issues:

1. You say that the BT1 tree is "not assumed to be binary" -- but it's defined to be a binary tree. Did you mean, say, that it's not assumed to be *complete* or something like that?
2. Did you want the "Leaves" to not have elements on them? You could call it `Empty` if that's your goal, rather than `Lf`.

As for writing this in a Haskell-like way, probably the best way is to import `Traversable`:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable
import Data.Foldable

data Tree x = Empty | Tree (Tree x) x (Tree x)

instance Traversable Tree where
    traverse _ Empty = pure Empty
    traverse fb_a (Tree left a right) = 
        Tree <$> traverse fb_a left <*> fb_a a <*> traverse fb_a right

instance Functor Tree where fmap = fmapDefault
instance Foldable Tree where foldMap = foldMapDefault
```

With just those few lines of code, you get the power of `Data.Foldable`, which allows you to do pretty arbitrary agglomerations on the Tree. For example, you can convert the tree directly to a list using `toList`.

The type of `foldMap` is `Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m`. We can define a "searching for authors" using the `[x]` monoid as:

```
isAuthor :: String -> TrG -> [String]
isAuthor auth trg | auth `elem` trgAuthors trg = [trgTitle trg]
                  | otherwise = []
```

and then your code is `foldMap (isAuthor "Auguste Renoir") gtNam`. If you want to get the whole book entry and not just the title, you can replace `[trgTitle trg]` with `[trg]` above. In fact, there's a generic function which should be in Data.Foldable but isn't:

```
findAll :: (Foldable t) => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> [a]
findAll pred = foldMap (\a -> if pred a then [a] else [])
```

which is in some ways a "filter" on an arbitrary Foldable.

Comment: Note that ghc can derive Functor, Traversable and Foldable with `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable, DeriveFunctor -#}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I said that the tree is not assumed binary because I thought it is not with respect to "title" or "author" but it is with respect to "price". Has this some meaning?

Comment: I suppose, it would be better to see `filter :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m a) -> (a -> Bool) -> t a -> m a`, but could also be `concatMap (filter pred . (:[]))`

Comment: @user3166747 aha, you mean it's a binary *search* tree with regard to price. This does have some meaning -- it means that walking through the tree to find results "by price" is in many cases much easier than walking through the tree to find results by author (where you'll have to walk through the whole tree.)